# How to handle or integrate multiple step def files using Cucumber Selenium page factory?

Tags: cucumberjs

I have create a page factory framework using Cucumber, Selenium with js.
I have multiple step definition file one is for login and one is for logout.
IF I run single step def file it successfully get automated but when I want to automate first login then after successful login application should logout.
In my first step def file I have provided driver, browser information and in second step def file I have provided only webdriver and browser information.
I am not getting how to link second step def file with first to test end to end functionality.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code? This is not making much sense as to what your problem is via text.

Comment: I am unable to edit my post any other way to share my code.

Comment: you could push your code up to a git repository and I can check it out there and give feedback